# python: запись в список по нескольку значений за раз

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list, append

подскажите в питоне вообще можно ли реализовать такую вещь в 1 строку встроенными производительными средствами:

```
f = lambda x: x + 2
g = lambda x: x * 3

arr = [1, 2, 3]
res = []

for x in arr:
    res.append(f(x))
    res.append(g(x))
```

т.е. требуется создать новый массив где от каждого элемента старого массива будет получено 2 значения

очень бы хотелось чтобы существовало встроенное решение по типу:

```
tmp = [f(x), g(x) for x in arr]
```

но пока кажется что его нет
максимум во что можно схлопнуть начальное решение без потери производительности - это в

```
res = []

for x in arr:
    res += [f(x), g(x)]
```

или все таки существует решение (без привлечения дополнительных библиотек)?

Comment: хотелось бы понять чем не устраивает к примеру последнее решение `res += [f(x), g(x)]` или просто принципиально хочется однострочник?

Comment: `res.extend((f(x), g(x)))`.

Comment: `list(itertools.chain(*((f(x), g(x)) for x in arr)))`

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну это уже совсем "из пушки по воробьям", хотя методы всякие знать надо, конечно ))

Answer (score 4):

Можно же два цикла в списковом сокращении написать (да и вообще сколько угодно циклов при желании). И учесть при этом, что функции в питоне (включая и лямбды) - это обычные переменные, из них можно список или кортеж составить и перебрать его в цикле:

```py
res = [z(x) for x in arr for z in (f,g)]
```

Такое списковое сокращение даст на выходе "плоский" список, как и требуется.

По сути это аналог такого кода:

```py
res = []
for x in arr:
    for z in (f,g):
        res.append(z(x))
```

Comment: можно, но тут как раз встанет вопрос о производительности
в некоторых случаях имеем list compression и значительное повышение производительности

Comment: @Zhihar Что-то я вашу мысль совсем не понял :)

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант использовать `functools.reduce`:

```
reduce(lambda l, e: l + [f(e), g(e)], arr, [])
```

Этот вариант будет создавать новый список на каждой итерации, чтоб этого избежать, и делать только append-ы на оригинальном придется чуть усложнить:

```
reduce(lambda l, e: (l.append(f(e)), l.append(g(e)), l)[-1], arr, [])
```

Comment: Не стоит использовать функциональные конструкции ради побочных эффектов. Обычный цикл проще и понятнее.

Comment: Я согласен, обычный цикл лучше всего.